# Quotient of continuous local martingale with quadratic variation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, local-martingales

Consider a local martingale $(M_t)_{t\ge 0}$ with continuous paths and $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}[M]_t=\infty$ a.s.

I want to show, that

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{M_t}{[M]_t}=0\quad\text{a.s.}$$

I tried using fatou's lemma giving

\begin{align}
\liminf_{t\rightarrow\infty}E\bigg[\frac{M_t}{[M]_t}(1_{\{M_t<1\}}+1_{\{M_t\ge 1\}})\bigg]\le\liminf_{t\rightarrow\infty}E\bigg[\frac{M_t^2}{[M]_t}\bigg],
\end{align}

but I do not know how to go on further.

Another idea is to use borel-cantelli, since there are countable stopping times, I may be using solving this.

I would be grateful for any hint or help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you need the further condition that $\langle M,M \rangle_\infty = \infty$ a.s., otherwise you can take $M$ to be something like Brownian motion stopped at $t=1$.  Then you can use the method of time change: There exists a Brownian motion $B$ such that $M_t = B_{\langle M,M \rangle_t}$.  Since you can show for Brownian motion that $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{B_t}{t} = 0$ a.s., the result still holds when $t$ is replaced by an increasing function that converges to $\infty$ a.s. so

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{M_t}{\langle M,M \rangle_t} = \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{B_{\langle M,M \rangle_t}}{\langle M,M \rangle_t} = 0.$$

Comment: Yes, this information was missing! I already proved both of the properties you are mentioning, so I guess I will be able to finish the proof now. Thank you!

Comment: I also found a reference for $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{B_t}{t}=0$ here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1729071/why-does-the-borel-cantelli-lemma-finish-the-job-law-of-large-numbers-brownia